# How can I use window prompts/confirms and functions using math.floor/math.random to generate a password with an HTML button? (Javascript/HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, numbers

I'm trying to create a password generator using javascript and a generate password function tied to an HTML button with a 'click' event listener.

I have done all the work to get user-input, (created window prompt for password length, and window confirms for upper case, lower case, special characters, and numbers). I have created several functions which generate random outputs from a given range of the character code for each type.

How would I attach these randomizer functions into my generatePassword function so that they give back random values that correlate to the user-defined specifications and length?

I have tried creating an array of these functions, with no luck. I'm not sure how to iterate through the array at the given length, and everything I have tried has returned that these functions values are not defined.  I have only been using javascript for about 2 weeks.

```
//Window Prompts for user/ Event Listeners

function userinputLength(){
  var passLength = Number(window.prompt("How many characters in length should your password be? Enter a number between 8 and 128", ""));
   //Comparing input from user to see if it's valid 
    if (passLength >= 129 || passLength <= 7 ) {
      window.alert("That's outside of the given range, try again")
      userinputLength()
    }
    
    else {
   
    if (typeof(passLength) === "number"){
      console.log(passLength);
      window.alert("You have chosen " + passLength);
    } else if (typeof(passLength) === "string", "char"){
      console.log("NOT A NUMBER");
      window.alert("That's not a number, try again.");
      userinputLength()
    }
  }
    
  
  
  //Create a variable containing prompt/alert/something window for user defined types of characters (Upper-case, Lower-Case, Special Characters(MAY NEED MORE THAN ONE for letters, case, numbers, special characters)
};
//function asking user for uppercase or not
function passCase1() { 
  var passCaseconfirm1 = window.confirm("Do you want Upper case characters?")
      if (passCaseconfirm1 === true) {
        window.alert("You have chosen to use upper case characters.")
      }else {
        window.alert("You have chosen NOT to use upper case characters.")
      }
    console.log(passCaseconfirm1);

};
// function asking user if they want lower case characters or not
function passCase2() { 
  var passCaseconfirm2 = window.confirm("Do you want lower case characters?")
      if (passCaseconfirm2 === true) {
        window.alert("You have chosen to use lower case characters.")
      }else {
        window.alert("You have chosen NOT to use lower case characters.")
      }
      //USE UPPERCASE ARRAY
    
    console.log(passCaseconfirm2);

};

//function asking user for special characters or not
function passChar(){
  var passCharconfirm = window.confirm("Do you want to use special characters or not?");
  if (passCharconfirm) {
    window.alert("You have chosen to use special characters");
    //USE SPECIAL CHARACTERS ARRAY
  } else {
    window.alert("You have chosen NOT to use special characters");
    //DONT USE SPECIAL CHARACTERS ARRAY
  }
  console.log(passCharconfirm);
}  
// Function asking user if they want random numbers or not
function passNum(){
  var passNumconfirm = window.confirm("Do you want to use numbers or not?");
  if (passNumconfirm) {
    window.alert("You have chosen to use number");
    //USE SPECIAL CHARACTERS ARRAY
  } else {
    window.alert("You have chosen NOT to use numbers");
    //DONT USE SPECIAL CHARACTERS ARRAY
  }
  console.log(passNumconfirm);
}  

//Functions to get random output from character code. 


function getRandomLower() {
  return String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random() * 26) + 97);
}

function getRandomUpper() {
  return String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random() * 26) + 65);
}

function getRandomNumber() {
  return String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 48);
}

function getRandomSymbol() {
  const symbols = "!@#$%^&*()_+|\={}[]>?<;'./,"
  return symbols[Math.floor(Math.random() *  symbols.length)];
}

//Generate Password function and associated function calls. 
function generatePassword() {
  userinputLength();
  passCase1();
  passCase2();
  passChar(); 
  passNum();
  //NEED MORE FUNCTION CALLS HERE THAT DETERMINE IF EACH CASE IS TRUE OR FALSE AND RETURNS VALUE BASED ON LENGTH
  };

// Get references to the #generate element
var generateBtn = document.querySelector("#generate");

// Write password to the #password input
function writePassword() {
  var password = generatePassword();
  var passwordText = document.querySelector("#password");
  passwordText.value = password;
}

// Add event listener to generate button
generateBtn.addEventListener("click", writePassword);

//CALL FUNCTIONS
```

Comment: Inside of your `passLength` if statement, you're calling `userinputLength()` without returning, which means the rest of the function will later still be executed. I believe you meant something like `return userinputLength()`?

Comment: That's actually a loop set up so that if they give invalid input it takes them back to the beginning of the userinputLength function. The length has to be between 8-128 characters. Is there a better or different way to do that? Sorry if these are mega-newb questions.

Comment: It's fine that you're asking newbie questions; you just started. What I mean is, you are calling `userinputLength()` if user input is invalid, and after `userinputLength()` has finished the rest of the function body that called `userinputLength()` will then execute.

Comment: `if(typeof(passLength) === "number")` will execute no matter what, because you already converted `passLength` to a number. If you were wondering whether what the user provided was a number, you can do `if(passLength.toString() !== "NaN")` (`NaN` stands for *Not a Number*). Also, a user input that turns to `NaN` will be stopped at your first validation condition (`if(passLength >= 129 || passLength <= 7)`).

Comment: Use a while loop in `passLength()` as opposed to recursion. That way you won't have any problematic issues when it comes to coding in the return value. By recursion I mean you are calling `passLength()` from within itself (as @code noted)

Comment: @GetSet that works, but I don't see any problem with using recursion as long as it's returned.

Comment: I tend to agree, but OP isn't returning. Or OP could use global vars, but that would be teaching bad practice. Really this code needs to be rewritten from scratch without the `prompts` and `alerts`. Focus on the random password generator with supplied constants.